# How to compare unsigned char in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

After much reading of the answers here, I still haven't managed to make it work. I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) unsigned char theValue;
```

in `nonMutableClass` class, and can be set in `mutableClass` using

```
-(void)setTheValue:(unsigned char)value
```

Using the API, I could simply do `[mutableClass setTheValue:1];`, however, how do I check/compare it?
Checking it using this code doesn't seem to return true even if it's actually true:

```
if ([nonMutableClass.theValue == 1]) NSLog(@"TRUE");

if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)(nonMutableClass.theValue)] isEqualToString:@"1"]) NSLog(@"TRUE"); 
//This one returned as compiler error as "cast to 'char *' from smaller integer type 'unsigned char'"
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some really funny issues if you compare just the first character of a string. I think first though you need to create the string correctly. I'll post some code ...

Comment: Hmmmm ... shouldn't that be ```NSLog(@"TRUE")```

Comment: `if ([nonMutableClass.theValue == 1]) NSLog("TRUE");` doesn't compile, post real code please.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this to convert the character to a string.

```
NSString * s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c ];
```

or

```
NSString * s = [NSString initWithBytes:&c length:1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Note I am using ASCII here. Change to UTF8 or whatever your `c` represents. The first alternative uses C printf to convert.

Then to compare, something like

```
[str1 cmp:str2 options:x]
```

where you need to set `x` to what works in your situation. Here are some suggestions...

- NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
- NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch
- NSWidthInsensitiveSearch

You or (`|`) these together to get what you need. I mention these as the manual don't give you all of them and they can be extremely handy when working with characters. The type of character you are working with will dictate which of these you need.

Also, funny thing, if you compare just say the first character of a string, then do the compare on

```
[s substringToIndex:1]
```

as the alternative

```
[s1 compare:s2 options:x range:r]
```

goes haywire for some funny reason.